# How can I disable all the duplicate Texbox having same Id using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have  different number of TextBoxes with same Id.I am compelled to use same Id.I Do not have permission to use Class. I need to enable only the first TextBox and disable the rest.

Here is my code with 3 different TextBox :

```
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
```

I need output like this , I need to enable the first one and disable the rest :

```
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" disabled="disabled" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" disabled="disabled" required="required" placeholder="Son">
```

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` to get the inputs. Actually you shouldn't have multiple same ids in the document in the first place. It messes the use of `#` selector in CSS and prevents you to get a correct element with `getElementById`.

Comment: Use `name` if you want to differentiate, ID *should* be unique.

Comment: `I am compelled to use same Id.I Do not have permission to use Class` Having the same `id` repeated within a document is invalid. Whoever is denying you permission to change to classes is completely wrong.

Comment: My software company's requirement

Comment: Sounds like you need a new software company.

Comment: @AnujTamrakar, Do you use JQuery?

Comment: You can use `$('[id=abc]')` as selector. But not recommended.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan would work but i disagree to use it.

Comment: @Jai Yes. I am also reluctant. `My software company's requirement` what else can we do, with this person being in this kind of a situation.

Comment: @AnujTamrakar Are you allowed to use any other custom attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`ID`'s must be unique in an HTML page.**

That being said, if there is no other option for you because your company has a set of stupid norms, then you can use this. But using same id for different elements is ***not recommended***.

**jQuery solution.**

```js
$(function() {
  $('[id=abc]').slice(1).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
```

**JavaScript solution**:

```js
ele = document.querySelectorAll('[id="abc"]');
for (i = 0; i < ele.length; i++){
  ele[i].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
<input type="Textbox" id="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
```

Comment: the answer you have posted will work fine.But the actually the question  is How can I disable all the duplicate Texbox having same Id using `javascript` not `jQuery` :)

Comment: @shu the `jQuery` tag is there.

Comment: @shu : :) I added a js solution too. Should support from IE9

Comment: Start loop from 0. otherwise it will skip index 0 element.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script

```
var inputList = document.querySelectorAll('#abc');
console.log(inputList);
for(var index = 1; index < inputList.length; index++) {
    inputList[index].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var txt = $('#abc');
$.each(txt, function (index) {
    if(index > 0) {
        $(txt[index]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is used for unique identification. Ideally you should not use duplicate id.
In your case where you are not allowed to add class, you can add custom attribute as selector.

your HTML can be

```
<input type="Textbox" id="abc1" my-id="123" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" id="abc2" my-id="123" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" id="abc3" my-id="123" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
```

and your jquery can be

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "input[my-id='123']" ).not(':first').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
</script>
```

in case you dont allowed to add custom attribute the below jquery will work for HTML you provided

```
$( "#abc" ).not(':first').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use @satish-sam solution but use `name` property instead of id's:

Html

```
<input type="Textbox" name="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" name="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">

<input type="Textbox" name="abc" data-templatefieldid="12" required="required" placeholder="Son">
```

Javascript

```
var txt=$('[name="abc"]');
$.each(txt,function (index) {
  if(index>0)
  {
    $(txt[index]).attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one,This may help

```
function clearAll()
{
   var ele= document.getElementsById("myId");
     for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
      if(i>0)
        ele[i].disabled = true;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html) **id attribute have to be unique** in HTML page. And having more than one id (duplicate) in page is not standard.

But to find duplicate id's using JQuery you can use this code:

```js
  //See  console for duplicate ids
   $('[id]').each(function(){
  var id = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(id.length>1 && id[0]==this) {
    console.log('ID: '+ this.id + ' id duplicate');
    
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="a">A1</a>
<a id="b">B</a>
<a id="c">C</a>
<a id="a">A2</a>
```

*Instead of what return in console*, you can do what you like, for example disabling your text-box